# Swift 3: UITableView row height changes due to UINavigationViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have an UIViewController embedded into an `UINavigationController`. My `UIViewController` contain an `UITableView` that have two types of cells: cell1 (the first cell) have height = 250, and cell2 have height = 85. Everything works fine in the beginning but when I tape a cell to show its detail using `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)` , then when I return to the `parentViewController` (the one containing the `UITableView`) the cell1 got the height of cell2. In the storyboard I have set the rowHeight of the table as 250, for the view of the cell1 250  and for the cell2 one I have 85. Then in the controller I set the `table.rowHeight` in function of the `index.row` as you can see in the code above:

```
// MARK: - Table view

    private func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.dataSource.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 if indexPath.row == 0 {
            tableView.rowHeight = 260
            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "homeFirstTableViewCell") as? HomeFirstTableViewCell
//set the content of the cell
} else {
            tableView.rowHeight = 85
            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "homeTableViewCell") as? HomeTableViewCell
}
}
```

**Note:**

I have this problem only with the iOS 8 devices

**Edit:**

When I tried this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if(indexPath.row == 0 ){
            return 260
        }

        return 85
    }
```

The first cell having cell2 as type got the height of cell1

Comment: you should implement `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat` to set the row height

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the constraints of the content of your cells in the storyboard or xib (if you created them in one), one way to doing this is creating a `containerView` and assigning it a height constraint, and use this method

`tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat`

instead of this

`tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat`

And return an abstract number between 85 and 250

Comment: When I do that, all the cells got the height of the cell1 type (250)

Comment: Did you add a content view and assign it a height constraint to both your cells?

Comment: Yes I have already a content view with a height = 250 for cell1 and height = 85 for cell2